# Applications on my Windows 10 PC are not appearing properly

Tags: windows-10, netflix

Applications on my Windows 10 PC are not appearing properly graphically, and only text is being shown. How to solve this, is it a windows or graphics settings problem?

[image: Neflix home page]

[image: sign in screen only appearing as text]

Comment: It's a networking/connectivity problem. Start by power-cycling all networking hardware in your building - router, modem, wifi, switches, computers...

Comment: It is not a networking/connectivity issue as it is working very well in both of my other  PC's running on the same version of Windows.

Comment: OK, then don't. If you're going to fight even the first attempt at triaging an issue, then expect to have a hard ride.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off, and turning it back on again?  http://bit.ly/2Szc2RS

Comment: I did power cycling of all my devices on the network, still facing the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean you always have a white rectangle in the middle of the screen. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried turning it off and on about 3 times and have also tried resetting the app.

Comment: @harrymc No, there is not always a white triangle in the middle of the screen, just in the applications downloaded from windows store.

Comment: Try to [Reinstall all Windows Store apps](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/re-register-windows-store-apps).